# Add a list of questions selected for HNQ to the 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, hot-questions

Now that questions selected for Hot Network Questions have a record attached to them, those can be queried for in the Data Explorer.

However, the Data Explorer is only updated once a week. It would be nice to also have a full list of questions that are selected for Hot Network Questions and the times they were selected added to the 10k tools. In my opinion, it adds to the "bird's eye view" of the site that is afforded to them, and is in line with other similar lists (e.g. migrated questions, protected questions, etc.).

Also, a list of questions that were removed from Hot Network Questions by a moderator would be very nice as well.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with this feature request. It would be good for:

- checking for the quality of questions selected and editing if required
- looking for poor-quality questions which need to be removed from HNQ

> Also, a list of questions that were removed from Hot Network Questions by a moderator would be very nice as well.

This will be good for:

- looking at repeated questions which have to be removed by the same user
- detecting voting fraud (linked to above)